# How to set up CouchDB-Lucene on Android

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase, couchdb-lucene

We are enhancing an Android app to have advanced SEARCH features.

The app uses `Couchbase-mobile (version 2.0.0)` as a an Android service...

I have these questions with implementation:

1. How simple it is to integrate something like `[CouchDB-Lucene][1]`.
2. I guess we will have to trigger the couchdb-lucene java process on the Android device (as a service), but not sure if configuring the local Couchbase's `.ini` file is the only thing needed.
3. Is CouchDb-Lucene okay for Android or too heavy?

Would be great if anyone could provide some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone got started here: https://github.com/ArtooTrills/TouchDB-Android-Lucene

I should note that this version of the Android syncronizing database is old. We are working on a new lighter version of it, check out the Couchbase mobile mailing list to get the latest info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobile-couchbase

Comment: Thanks for that piece of info. Hope we get to see some clarity in the many variants of CouchDB floating around soon!